# Does Yii2 or Laravel5 compensate the weakness points in Codeigniter?

Tags: php, codeigniter, model-view-controller, laravel-5, yii2

I am a Web developer, I use Codeigniter from 3 years, and I used it in many production projects, also Codeigniter was my start point with developing projects based on framework.
Later, I noticed that other php frameworks provides many useful features that make developer life easier such as:

- **Database migration** which making altering database schema easier and more efficient
- **Code generation (scaffolding):** which generate model, view, and controller for the entity
- **Form validation:** form validation rules is determined in generation and framework do the rest
- **REST API:** Support REST Controller natively in framework without third party plugin

All these reasons make me thinking to switch to other framework.

After searching, I found Laravel5 have features that I need, also It has a big community of developers.

My friend use Yii2 and he recommend me to switch to Yii2, also I found statistics both Laravel and Yii has good reputation in these statistics.

How Laravel5 and Yii2 Differ from other and which added value for each framework

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I can only give you the experience we here at [Sourcetoad](http://sourcetoad.com) have had:

1) Production ready: Yii2 follows [semver](http://semver.org/) (like the rest of the PHP community/eco-system), when the framework is patched the changes are predictable and well advertised ahead of time.

2) Learning curve: Laravel wins out here; many more tutorials, cookbooks, web resources, and personnel.

3) Security: From our experience Yii/2 goes above and beyond. Not just configurable, not optional, nearly every standard security practice is active by default.

4) As you pointed out scaffolding: Yii/2 wins out here. From Gii onward scaffolding generation is a breeze.

5) Community: While we here have not needed to overly engage the community around each framework they are both part of the OSS community; however our initial impression is the Laravel might/maybe nudge ahead here. No conclusive examples to go on.

In the end the answer is: [right tool, right job](http://media.propertycasualty360.com/propertycasualty360/article/2013/07/27/19.jpg).

Answer (score 4):

## Introduction

I've been a senior full stack developer for +3 years and mainly i use Yii for php development But i was told that laravel is better so i decided to build an [eCommerce Script](https://github.com/jawsaqlabs/laraCommerce) with laravel to get to know laravel more and to see the difference between Yii and laravel.

### So finally what the difference between laravel and Yii?

**in a few words** mainly Nothing , But Yii has a better way to deal with forms.

#### details

1. **easiness to learn**: if you're an experienced developer it will take about an hour to learn each one of the frameworks. and both of the frameworks has an helpful documentation.
2. **dealing with rest api**:both of them make producing REST APIs easy and both has its own way. but i use Laravel when developing rest api cause laravel more helpful when developing using [microservices architecture](http://microservices.io/index.html).
3. **developers community** it might seem that laravel has a larger community of developers but during my career with Yii i've found no bottleneck of having a question without an answer.
4. **jobs Chances** You'll get a better chance to find a job if you're an experienced laravel developer rather than Yii.

### finally:

it's up to you what to choose cause both of frameworks is powerful and helpful

Comment: trying to find out what is full stack developer. Could you please be nice and explain what full stack developer is?

Answer (score 4):

Yes!, Laravel5 or Yii2 has built-in features that Codeigniter lacks.

For me I've been using laravel for about 5 months, it has some strong features like ORM (Eloquent), DB Migration, Form validation, REST API, HTTP Middlewares, and scaffolding (using a third-party).

I've never used Yii before, so I can't tell differences between the two, but also it sounds that it has some good features, But it is said that developers go through four stages:

1. No framework
2. Use a framework.
3. Write own framework.
4. No framework.

An interesting article to read about this [link](https://philsturgeon.uk/php/2014/01/13/the-framework-is-dead-long-live-the-framework/).

> These days all you need to do is grab a bunch of components that work together (relying on each other, or working despite each other), bootstrap them altogether, set up some routing, hook up a config system, lay your controllers out, handle session configuration and connect to your database.
>
> You can do that completely with random pick-and-mixed Composer components. But when you've done writing that application layer… 
> guess what you've done?
>
> You've just written a framework.
>
> Sturgeon, L. (n.d.). The "Framework" is Dead, Long live the Framework. Retrieved July 11, 2016, from https://philsturgeon.uk/php/2014/01/13/the-framework-is-dead-long-live-the-framework/

Finally, there's no perfect answer for your question, everyone is using his favorite option, some prefer using a framework, some prefer to go custom. You just stick to what you feel comfortable with, and always try to find better ones.

Answer (score 1):

Nobody will be able to answer this for you. It's a matter of personal taste I think. I think Laravel has a larger community behind it but that's probably up for discussion. What I usually do is to create a small todo app in different frameworks to see where I see fit for myself.

What I personally like about Laravel is that Laravel has also developed Lumen and Spark which are very useful in itself. On the other side, Spark is a paid effort and this seems to generate a lot of discussion on the future of Laravel.